# Showing Id instead of Name in Active Admin Gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I installed Ruby on Rails Gem `Active Admin` and made association between tables.

```
Category 
with fields (category_name:string)
```

with

```
SubCategory
with fields (sub_category_name:string, category_id:integer)
```

but when i view admin console for subcategory in drop down for categories instead of their name encrypted string is coming which refers to category id. Its like:

```
#<Category:0x698a648>
#<Category:0x6958998>
```

I want category name to be here. I know `def to_s` function can do it but in active admin gem i am not sure where to write this function.

Any Idea will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could code the to_s method in the class and return the category name:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category    
  #...

  def to_s
    category_name
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i know i can do it in category.rb but it will not reflect on active admin console i guess. i am using active admin gem where i have pages in admin folder separately and there i lready tried above function but with no success.

Comment: ActiveAdmin tries to call a method "to_s" from the class definition of the object. If you define the method in the model, ActiveAdmin will find it and it will work.